# exercise on groups

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following database:

`Prof(profBadge, profName, Department)
Course(courseCod,  courseName, profBadge, area)
Class(classCode, date, courseCod, numberOfStudents)`

And the following request:
For each professor who has only courses in the area databases show the badge number and the course which the highest average number of students.

```
Create view badgeList(profBadge, courseCod) as
SELECT DISTINCT profBadge, courseCod
FROM Coure
WHERE (profBadge NOT IN (SELECT profBadge
                   FROM Course
                   WHERE Area <> 'database'));

Create view avgLessons(AvgStud, courseCod) as
SELECT AVG(numberOfStudents), courseCod
FROM class
GROUP BY courseCod;

Create view MaxStudent(maxStu, profBadge) as
select max(med.avgStud), el.profBadge
from avgLessons med, badgeList el
where med.courseCod= el.courseCod
group by el.profBadge;

select DISTINCT MS.profBadge, MS.MAXSTU, Corso.CODCORSO
from MaxStudent MS, course, class
where MS.profBadge = course.profBadge and MS.maxStu = class.numberOfStudents and course.courseCod = class.courseCod;`
```

Comment: Break it down into parts.  First how do you find the course with the higest number of average students?  then how do you join that back to your dataset and display the badge and course number for 'database' courses?

Comment: But if I find the course with the highest number, I lose the informations of the other courses, or not? I need to find the course with the highest number of avg students for EACH professor

Comment: so include in that calculation a group by on the profbadge. and join back using the badge and course.  What I'm trying to avoid is writing the answer for you but rather guide you to steps to try and get you to a solution/attempt yourself.  that old teach a person to fish they eat for life give em a fish they eat for a day.  Don't eat the whole elephant, just one bite at a time and see how it comes together.  Complex things broken down into component parts become simple and when you put the components back it's no longer complex.

Comment: I am with xQbert  here. Do this step by step. First step: Find professors who only have  courses in the area databases. Think about an approach. Come back when you have problems.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I've already solved that problem finding the professors who have courses also in other areas and then selecting those who weren't part of that list

Comment: @xQbert I edited the question and wrote my code, I think it's correct now, but could you look at it please?

Comment: You shouldn't use comma-separated joins anymore. They were made redundant in 1992. Nowadays you should use explicit ANSI joins instead: `FROM MaxStudent ms INNER JOIN course ON ms.profBadge = course.profBadge`.

Comment: Do you have a sample dataset that you can try this against?  From what I see you have a few typo's  corso doesn't seem to be an alias or table.   I'd use inner join notation instead of the `,` separation as `inner join` is the ANSI standard since 1992 (but both work). use of distinct may be unnecessary.   But your approach is solid; breaking down each needed requirement into a component query and then putting them together.  This could be done via subqueries or using common table expressions so you don't clutter the database with added objects; but if they may be reused... not a bad idea!

Comment: My next steps would be to have a sample data set for each table built along with edge cases, min max ties to ensure we get the right badge and course for the sample data. Not only does this give you experience building data/tables; but it lets you see if what you built meets your expectations.  I think your close but you have a few syntax errors to resolve.

Comment: Your last query doesn't work. You got the avarage number of students per course, e.g. 12.5, and took the maximum per professor. But that doesn't necessarily match `class.numberOfStudents` of course. You'd have to join against `avgLessons` not `class`.

Comment: @xQbert I don't have any database it's just that I'm italian and I translated the code before posting it. Syntax errors are caused by the same reason.

Comment: @thorstenkettner you're right about join, but our teacher uses this method, I don't know why. However thanks to both of you!

Comment: This is certainly no easy task. I've had to edit my answer, for it had flaws too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I see what you want to achieve, but the code below returns profBadges and only those courseNames which have highest average number of students (counting through number of belonging classes).

```
SELECT profBadge,
  courseName
FROM
  (SELECT C.profBadge,
    C.courseName,
    SUM(CL.numberOfStudents)                                                      /COUNT(CL.classCode)  AS Avg_Students_Num,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY C.profBadge ORDER BY SUM(CL.numberOfStudents)/COUNT(CL.classCode)) AS Rank
  FROM Course C
  LEFT JOIN Class CL
  ON CL.courseCod=C.courseCod
  GROUP BY C.courseName,
    C.profBadge
  )
WHERE Rank=1
```

Comment: Didn't handle only professors with 'database' area only.

Answer (score 0):

This is no easy task. As mentioned, do this step by step.

Step 1: professors with only courses in area 'database'. Using `NOT IN` as you did is one way to solve this. Another (and usually the quickest) is aggregation.

```
SELECT profBadge
FROM Course
GROUP BY profBadge
HAVING MIN(Area) = 'database' AND MAX(Area) = 'database';
```

Step 2: Average numbers of students per course, as you show yourself.

```
SELECT courseCod, AVG(numberOfStudents)
FROM class
GROUP BY courseCod;
```

Step 3: Combine the two. You select courses where the profBadge is in the first set (query from step 1) and you rank them by average number of students (for which you have to join the query from step 2).

```
SELECT courseCod, courseName, profBadge, area
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    c.courseCod, c.courseName, c.profBadge, c.area,
    RANK() OVER (PARTION BY c.profBadge ORDER BY av.avgNum DESC) AS rn
  FROM Course c
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT courseCod, AVG(numberOfStudents) AS avgNum
    FROM class
    GROUP BY courseCod
  ) av ON av.courseCod = c.courseCod
  WHERE c.profBadge IN
  (
    SELECT profBadge
    FROM Course
    GROUP BY profBadge
    HAVING MIN(Area) = 'database' AND MAX(Area) = 'database'
  )
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```